# moving average or rolling mean pandas without any window size

Tags: python, pandas, mean, moving-average

How do i calculate a rolling mean or moving average where i consider all the items that I have seen so far.

Lets say I have a data-frame like below

```
   col   new_col
0    1      1
1    2      1.5
2    3      2
```

and so on. 
Now i would like to add a new column where i caclulate the average of all the items in col until that point.
Specifying a window will mean that i will get the first few as Nan and then it only does a rolling window. But i need something like above.

Comment: [Expanding window moment functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions)

Comment: For your case, it is `df.expanding().mean()`. I couldn't find a better duplicate target but I that post summarizes expanding calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below will do exactly what you're requesting. There is plenty of room for improvement though. It uses a for loop with an if-else statetment. There are surely faster ways to do this with a vectorized function. It will also trigger the [SettingsWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) if you omit the `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` part.

But it does the job:

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Settings
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

# Dataframe with desired input
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1,2,3]})

# Make room for a new column
df['new_col'] = np.nan

# Fill the new column with values
for i in df.index + 1:
    if i == 0:
        df['new_col'].iloc[i] = np.nan
    else:
        df['new_col'].iloc[i-1] = pd.rolling_mean(df.col.iloc[:i].values, window = i)[-1]
print(df)
```

#### Output:

[image]